# WPF - RichTextEditor

Tags: wpf, xaml, flowdocument, rich-text-editor

im searching for a Usercontrol that generates XAML-Code (Flowdocument Code)

For a Bold Text -> `<Paragraph><Bold>Text</Bold></Paragraph>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the RichTextBox in the Extended WPF Toolkit - http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RichTextBox

I haven't tried it, but according to the documentation it has a XamlFormatter as well.

Comment: I found a easy way, (im just wpf/c# beginner...) the RichTextBox has a Property called Document. That is a FlowDocument :)

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

From what kind of object do you want to generate the Xaml-code?

If it is a TextBox content you could try to use some Converter classes.